# Creating External Content Type under BCS model by connecting to an Oracle Database

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs, external-content-type, external-list, oracle

I want to create an External content type by connecting to an Oracle database using VS or SP designer,to show data in an external list?

I am a bit new to BCS model so a little background will be helpful.

Any help is welcomed ! Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via SharePoint designer by

- Creating a [database Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server.aspx) to connect to the remote Oracle table by installing OLEDB client on the SQL server only.
- Then use SharePoint designer to build your external content type from SQL Server.

For more detail steps check [SharePoint 2013:BCS Connect To Oracle DB No Code](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30887.sharepoint-2013-bcs-connect-to-oracle-db-no-code.aspx)

If you need to build BCS via Visual studio check [How to connect to the Oracle database using Business Connectivity Services (BCS)](https://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/how-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database-using-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Also, you can use [Meta Man](https://lightningtools.com/products/bcs-meta-man-windows/) to [Build External Content Types for Oracle](https://lightningtools.com/bcs/business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint-2013-and-oracle-using-meta-man/), ODBC, WCF, Salesforce, Dynamics CRM, OData and Microsoft SQL without code. But unfortunately it requires a license

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Visual Studio?Actually while making BDC model i am not able to save External content types and it is not appearing when clicking on external list. Also i am doing it in sandbox VM SP2013 where oracle client site is blocked.so effectively i cannot download anything.

Comment: I have attached a link to can create this via visual studio, but at any case you will need to use oracle client.if you can't use oracle client  you can build a web service at oracle server side and consume it at SharePoint side !